# I like your taste in stroller. You too. What does "you too" mean?

Tags: expressions

A and B are meeting for the first time. They both take a baby in a stroller.

> A: Hey I like your taste in stroller.

> B: You too.

What does *you too* mean?

Does it mean *I like your taste in stroller too*?

---

A is a boy, and B is a girl. They are teens. They take out their baby siblings to a park. Their strollers look exactly the same in everything. A is accosting B.

Comment: "You too" isn't quite right here. If it had a question mark it would mean, "Do you? You're not the only one". Perhaps B meant, "I like _yours_". BTW, it should be "I like your taste in stroller**s**," or just "I like your stroller".

Comment: If you read this somewhere you must say where and quote the source. If it was from a show please say which. If you created the dialogue that should be made clear.

Comment: Are A and B both women, men or one of each? There could be a hidden gag there. Not saying there must be,  just there might be.

Answer (score 5):

There are issues with both statements.

"I like your taste in stroller" sounds wrong. I would expect it to be plural, '*strollers*'. A person's 'taste' is their judgement of things within a certain field, so a "taste *in*" something would be followed by either a plural (eg cars, men) or a non-countable noun (eg food, wine, decor). Having said that, judging a person's taste in stroller based on one stroller is a bit weird anyway. I would probably say "I like your *choice* of stroller", or just "I like your stroller".

"You too" sounds like the wrong response because the original statement was about themselves ("*I* like...."). We would say "you too" in response to something that was directed at us, for example:

> -Enjoy your weekend!
> -You too!

One appropriate response to this would be "*likewise!*"; or much more informally "*snap!*", or "*ditto!*".

Comment: Unfortunately, "You too!" is often used erroneously as a "Yeah, back at ya!" statement, a sort of knee-jerk response to a compliment or encouragement. This is possibly where this confusion stems from. I've done it and always feel a bit dumb afterwards, like when a waiter tells you to enjoy your meal or someone wishes you the best of luck in a test they aren't taking.

Comment: I second @DoctorPenguin. One can hear "You too" as a casual answer to "I love you" or "Good to see you" because there the long replies include "you too" too so it makes some sense.

Comment: @DoctorPenguin I've certainly heard people make mistakes while speaking but I don't think we're here to teach the mistakes. It *is* wrong.

Comment: @Astralbee I absolutely agree that it's wrong, I never claimed otherwise. It is, however, a common enough mistake that I do think it's worth highlighting (which isn't necessarily "teaching" people to do it themselves).

Comment: @DoctorPenguin Fair point, I might have taken your original comment the wrong way, with you opening with "unfortunately..." it did seem like it was an attack on my answer. Yes, it's something people often say by accident, like calling a teacher "mom".